# Appcelerator Titanium and Web Authentication - Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-acs

Forgive me, but this is a vague question:

I am wanting to build an Android and iOS application to interact with my web application.

For example: Within my Android and iOS app, I am wanting to authenticate the users through my current web application, which currently is Laravel 4.2. The only tutorial I can find (which I'm sure is out of date) is - [TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-user-authentication-part-1--mobile-3728)

My question is, do you have any more recent tutorials on web authentication (registering users with their tokens) / push notifications (sent from a server) etc... The script I can see on the above example is both vulnerable to MYSQL injection and has a lack of SSL.

Many thanks for your help in this. I know there is no right and wrong answer, this is mainly just for guidance for someone starting out in mobile development!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HttpClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)

Appcelerator has an example in there.

In essence, you're posting to the same URL as your web page, or another with a more mobile appropriate response

As for SQL injection, you can perform basic validation yourself, but remember for Http requests, clients can be bypassed, which is why you want your validation to be server side